# Visual Studio Watch Window show WClass whenever I debug a simple windows application from its execuatble

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

Here's the code for just displaying a window using WinApi
For ref this code is from [here](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/simple_window.html).

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";

// Step 4: the Window Procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    // Step 2: Creating the Window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        "The title of my window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // Step 3: The Message Loop
    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Then I open the executable in Visual Studio 2019 with:

```
cl -Zi example.cpp user32.lib
devenv example.exe
```

When I run it using `F5`, I get this in the Watch Window:

> **NAME** = WClass
> **VALUE** = Unable to evaluate the expression. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057.

On hovering over the `VALUE` I get this: `The value for this item is stale due to a problem that occurred while evaluating it.`
On hovering over the refresh button I get this: `The value of this expression may be incorrect. It could not be evaluated because: "`
This problem however does not arise when I open a Windows Application Project in Visual Studio and dump this code. In that case, when I build the solution, the Watch Window is empty.

PS: The Program runs properly as expected but I am curious why WClass shows up in Watch Window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [watch window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows) doesn't do anything on its own. The user has to enter a symbol or expression for it to become active.

If your watch window shows an entry with name `WClass`, then that's an entry you entered. Given the code you provided, there is no symbol with that name, so the debugger cannot evaluate it.

If this is freaking you out, just delete the entry in your watch window. When done, switch to the [Autos and Locals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/autos-and-locals-windows) window. That's probably what you were looking for anyway.

Comment: I completely forgot watch window keeps the previous entries (though tbh I dont remember entering the WClass ). Anyway, thanks.